# Same words are disappearing

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net

I want to highlight a particular word and do a hover from gridview. My problem is if the word is repeated in the page the word is highlighted but other same words are disappearing form the text. Image for before and after highlight is attached. I have attached image of missing words before and after highlighting. Please help.

[image]

Page1.aspx

```
 protected void GridView3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["Pa"] = GridView3.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text;
            Session["paId"] = GridView3.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
            string sValue = ((HiddenField)GridView3.SelectedRow.FindControl("HiddenField1")).Value;
            Session["panode"] = sValue;
            Session["patt"] = GridView3.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Text.ToString().Trim('\n');
            Response.Redirect("selectipc.aspx");
             
             
        }
```

page2.aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                 <script>
                     $(function () {
                         var searchWord = $("#hfWord").val();
                         var iframeHtml = $("#hfHTML").val();
                         var index = iframeHtml.indexOf(searchWord);
                         if (index >= 0) {
                             iframeHtml = iframeHtml.substring(0, index) + "<span id='lblHighlight' style='background-color: yellow;'>"
                             + iframeHtml.substring(index, index + searchWord.length) + "</span>" + iframeHtml.substring(index + searchWord.length);
                         }
                         $('#frmDisplay').contents().find('body').html(iframeHtml);
                         if ($('#frmDisplay').contents().find('#lblHighlight').length > 0) {
                             $('#frmDisplay').contents().find('#lblHighlight')[0].scrollIntoView()
                         }
                     });
</script>

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Session.Add("Logintype", Session["new"].ToString());
            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
 if (Session["paId"] != null)
                {
                    hfWord.Value = Session["pa"].ToString();
                    getPa();
                    //Session.Contents.Remove(Session["Pa"].ToString());
                }
             }
         }

 public void getPa()
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connString"].ConnectionString);
            string panode = Session["panode"].ToString();
            string pstext = Session["pa"].ToString();
            string patext = Session["patt"].ToString();
            string vc = (Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["VCN"])).ToString();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select bn.vcFilePath from tblBookNodes bn inner join tbl_Pannotation pa on bn.iModuleId=pa.iNodeId where bn.iModuleId='" + panode + "' ", conn);
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    bytesp = (byte[])dr["vcFilePath"];
                    conn.Close();
                }
  getpa();
        }


public void getpa()
        {
            string panId = Session["paId"].ToString();
            string pstext = Session["pa"].ToString();
            string patext = Session["patt"].ToString();
            string fileName = panId.Replace(" ", "_") + ".htm";
            //string returnpath = "File/htmlFile/";
            string strPath = Server.MapPath("~/htmlFile/");
            //if (Directory.Exists(strPath))
            //{
            //    Directory.Delete(strPath, true);
            //}
            if (!Directory.Exists(strPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(strPath);
            }
            //string pth = strPath;
            string path = strPath + fileName;
            var doc = new HtmlDocument();
            string html = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesp);
            doc.LoadHtml(html);
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            var hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(path);
            sWriter.Write(sw.ToString());
            doc.Save(sWriter);
            sWriter.Close();
            //string fileContents = html;
            string searchText = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(pstext);
            string newBookmarktag = "<style>font.tip {border - bottom: 1px dashed;text - decoration: none}font.tip:hover {cursor: help;position: sticky}font.tip span {display: none}font.tip:hover span {background-color:F0E6BC;text-align:center;color:Black;font-weight:bold;border: #c0c0c0 1px dotted;padding: 5px 20px 5px 5px;display: block;z - index: 1000;left: 0px;margin: 10px;position: absolute;top: 10px;text - decoration: none}</style><font style=background-color:yellow class=tip><a name=" + pstext + ">" + "<span>" + patext + "</span></a></font>";
             
            // pstext = newBookmarktag;
            html = html.Replace(searchText, newBookmarktag);
            //hfHTML.Value = html;
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, html);
            hfHTML.Value = File.ReadAllText(path);
            //HiddenField1.Value = html;
 
            Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
            MultiView control = ((IETM.select)(page)).MultiView1;
            View View1 = (View)control.FindControl("View1");
            HtmlControl ctrl = (HtmlControl)View1.FindControl("frmDisplay");
            frmDisplay.Attributes.Add("src", HttpContext.Current.Request.Url + "/.." + "\\htmlFile\\" + fileName);
            MultiView1.SetActiveView(View1);
        }
```

Comment: Please use StackOverflow's image hosting (you can paste an image directly into the question edit box)

Comment: The appearance of that random `>` after the first highlight makes me suspect you're damaging the html with stray angle brackets; examine the html source; probably the words are still there but turned into html tags and disappearing as a result. Work out where in the code you insert highlighting tags and check that it's creating well formed html

Comment: Where am i doing wrong? Can u please explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

indexOf return only first value position
better use split in this case

```js
 $(function () {
     var searchWord = $("#hfWord").val();
     var iframeHtml = $("#hfHTML").val();
     iframeHtml = iframeHtml.split(searchWord).join("<span style='background-color: yellow;' class='lbl-highlight'>"+searchWord+"</span>");
     $('#frmDisplay').contents().find('body').html(iframeHtml);
     if ($('#frmDisplay').contents().find('.lbl-highlight').length > 0) {
       $('#frmDisplay').contents().find('.lbl-highlight')[0].scrollIntoView()
     }
 });
```

Comment: The above script wont jump to word everytime we have to scroll the whole page to search for highlighted word.

Comment: ok. code is edited, id is unique better use className

Comment: it working fine . when i do hover for tat highlighted text https://imgur.com/wfe0kXF . I don't understand y its showing like in the image link above.   Hover code is in the question as 'string newbookmarktag'. Sry am new to this dunno how to add code in comments.